# Tensorflow Build Failure with Bazel

Tags: python, tensorflow, bazel

Apologies in advance for the text dump

I am attempting to compile Tensorflow in OSX 10.13.4 using Bazel based on these instructions:
https://medium.com/xplore-ai/nvidia-egpu-macos-tensorflow-gpu-the-definitive-setup-guide-to-avoid-headaches-f40e831f26ea

I attempted the build using the following command:

```
bazel build --config=cuda --config=opt --cxxopt="-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0" --action_env PATH --action_env LD_LIBRARY_PATH --action_env DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

Here are the versions of all relevant programs:
Python: 3.6
CUDA: 10.0
cuDNN: 7.4
Tensorflow: https://github.com/zylo117/tensorflow-gpu-macosx
GPU: NVIDIA GTX 980
Bazel Version: 0.16.1

Here is the verbose error information along with some run info:

```
5 warnings generated.

ERROR: /Users/brianmoser/tensorflow-gpu-macosx/tensorflow/core/kernels/BUILD:3423:1: error while parsing .d file: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_brianmoser/9608e82147ff56f68b42fd19bee93cb0/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/darwin-opt/bin/tensorflow/core/kernels/_objs/bincount_op_gpu/bincount_op_gpu.cu.d (No such file or directory)  nvcc fatal : The version ('10.0') of the host compiler ('Apple clang') is not supported  Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build  Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.  INFO: Elapsed time: 1407.017s, Critical Path: 63.10s  INFO: 2389 processes: 2389 local.  FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully 
Additionally, here is the final step the build conducted:

tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:1506:19: warning: private field 'data_type_' is not used [-Wunused-private-field] cudnnDataType_t data_type_;
```

Finally, here is the final relevant information:

```
git rev-parse HEAD  795d7c36152a1f96adca0c48f4537e500f5ad36b 
bazel version  Build label: 0.16.1  
Build target:
bazel-out/darwin-opt/bin/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/BazelServer_deploy.jar
```

Does anybody have any idea what could be the reason for this error?

Comment: did you read error message? There is `The version ('10.0') of the host compiler ('Apple clang') is not supported `. There is also `... (No such file or directory)`. Maybe it needs something more to compile it. instruction in your link is 1 year old and `tensorflow` could change many elements in code.